# Is there a easy way to make a keystroke detector that would change to color of a button? (like for streaming overlays)

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to coding and was wondering if anyone could help me. I'm using a Windows forms app.

This is what i have so far but it only detects the button if i click it with my mouse first:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Button1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then Button1.BackColor = Color.DimGray
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Button1.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then Button1.BackColor = Color.White
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Button2.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then Button2.BackColor = Color.DimGray
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Button2.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then Button2.BackColor = Color.White
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You can set the `Form.KeyPreview = true` and use the Form's `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events the same way you're using the Buttons' (removing the Buttons' handlers). Unless you mean that you want this action to be performed from anywhere in the System (I'm not sure how *streaming overlays* compares to what you're doing here).

Comment: Is the intention to have your application trap keystrokes while it is **NOT** in focus?  If so, then there is no "easy" way.  Search for WH_KEYBOARD_LL...

Comment: im trying to make something like this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA1SmI8nfY4

Comment: Just looking at the video, trying to recreate that in WinForms will be more difficult than doing so with WPF. You should stop using WinForms and focus on WPF.

Comment: Whats WPF? (Im sorry im new) And do you know if theres any tutorials on yt that would go over the basic of how to make something like that?

Comment: You'll definitely need a low level keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL).  You can mimic the interface by defining a GraphicsPath with rectangles representing the position of your buttons, then setting the Region property of your form to that GraphicsPath.  This will REMOVE all of your form except where the rectangles are.  The app you are developing is NOT trivial.